# Java Finding Color of a Character in RTF Doc

Tags: java, colors, rtf

I have a question regarding Rich Text Format files. I need to be able to read a character in from a file and determine what its actual color is within the file.

I have found JavaRTFKit but from what I can tell it does not offer this functionality.

The parsing is not an issue I only need a way to determine the color, if this is even possible.

Any suggestions / direction is much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: so what is you question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to determine the color, but it looks like you might need to make your own parser rather than using a third-party library. The latest spec for RTF is at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10725